# Why is my update statement clearing all data from the record in my ASP.NET Core Application?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I thought I had this approach nailed down but I'm getting an odd result.  I have a form that passes in a ViewModel to my controller.  From there the controller extracts the passed in data, assigns it to the entity and then calls `Update` and `SaveChanges`.  However, the update wipes all data from my database row leaving only the modified data I passed in.

It was my understanding that calling `Update` meant that `ef` could detect which items were modified and update accordingly.  Have I got this wrong?

Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPositionFixture(ViewPosition model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && model != null)
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture
        {
            Id = model.FixtureId,
            WorkRole = model.TempScope
        };
        _context.Fixture.Update(fixture);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}
```

My context is injected beforehand:

```
private readonly MyContext _context;

public PositionController(HaglandContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Comment: I see no generic repository in your code, just an EF context. Where's the generic repository? By the way, in your action method, you should probably follow the [Post Redirect Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) rather than just returning a view.

Comment: Ok, thanks for commenting, the returned view is only for the sake of this question.

Comment: @Yanayaya did you find an answer to your question ?